# to initialize(allocate) base class shared_ptr with derived class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, shared-ptr

I have shape classes, and in the base class I have postfix and prefix operator overloadings as pure virtual.

```
class Shape
{
public:
  virtual Shape& operator ++()=0;
  virtual shared_ptr<Shape> operator++(int)=0;
  virtual void showPos()const =0;
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
  virtual Shape& operator ++() override; 
  virtual shared_ptr<Shape> operator ++(int) override;
  virtual void showPos()const override;
private:
  int x=0,y=0;
};
```

There is no problem, about prefix operator overloadings. In postfix I need to return a temp variable but I can not instantiate the abstract base class, so I decided to use shared_ptr as smart pointer.

```
void
Circle::showPos()const{ 
  cout << "X:"<< x <<", Y:"<<y <<endl;
  return;
}

Shape&
Circle::operator ++() {
  ++x;
  ++y;
  return *this;
}

shared_ptr<Shape>
Circle::operator ++(int) {
  shared_ptr<Shape> temp (Circle(*this));
  ++x;
  ++y;
  return temp;
}

int main()
{
  Circle myCircle;  

  myCircle.showPos(); //must be | X:0, Y:0
  (myCircle++)->showPos();//must be | X:0, Y:0 (now x=1,y=1)
  (myCircle++)->showPos(); //must be | X:1, Y:1 (now x=2,y=2)
  return 0;
}
```

Implementation is in the same file and like above.
And the error is,

```
main.cpp:38:40: error: no matching function for call to
'std::shared_ptr<Shape>::shared_ptr(Circle)'
shared_ptr<Shape> temp (Circle(*this));
```

How should I use shared_ptr ?

Comment: shared_ptr still needs to be assigned a pointer rather than a value.  That's why the function call doesn't match anything.

Comment: as far as I see, the problem about this line || shared_ptr<Shape> temp (Circle(*this)); || But I did not understand what exactly you mean. Can you explain a little deeper ?

Comment: Maybe you want to check out `make_shared`

Comment: Thank you very very much JVApen. It seem it works by now.

Comment: You'll still want to learn the difference between value and pointer, and between automatic, static, and dynamic storage.  All `make_shared` is doing is hiding this stuff a bit by returning a `shared_ptr`; there are some details that are different and important but they can wait in lieu of learning the topics I mentioned.